# How to 'grep' a continuous log file stream with 'tailf' and when the needed string is obtained, close/break the 'tailf' automatically?

Tags: bash, grep, tail

into a bash script, I need to grep a contiuous log streaming and when the proper string is filtered, I need to stop the 'tailf' command to move ond with other implementations.

The common command that works is:

```
tailf /dir/dir/dir/server.log | grep --line-buffered "Started in"
```

after the "Started in" line is gathered, I need to break down the "tailf" command.

All this stuff into a bash script.

Answer (score 2):

use `grep -m1`, it means return the first match then stop:

> -m num, --max-count=num 
>          Stop reading the file after num matches.

```
tailf /dir/dir/dir/server.log | grep -m1 "Started in"
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out...

```
tailf /dir/dir/dir/server.log | while read line
do
    echo $line | grep "thing_to_grep"
        if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
        echo "";echo "[ message ]";echo "";
        kill -2 -$$
    fi  
done
```

$$ is the PID of the current shell, in this case associated to the "tailf" command.

Comment: ha, why bother to `kill` whole shell, impressive, doesn't `grep -m1` work for you? if you like *your way*, improve it with `break`: `tailf  a.log | while read line; do echo "$line" | grep "word" && break; done`, don't forget double quote.

Comment: hey there any feedback?